# Can't access the database values using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to insert value into Oracle DB using JdbcTemplate, but its throwing the following exception:

> Can't access the database values using JdbcTemplate.

This is how I am trying to insert the values to the DB:

```
package com.sample.common.Dao;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
public class UserDao  extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    public void insert(){
        System.out.println("Tring to insert");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO SB_TBL_USER (user_id,user_password,user_name,user_email,user_mobile)"+" "
   +"VALUES ('test12', 't1est1', 't2est2', 't7est2','t7estm')";
    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        UserDao dao= new UserDao();
        dao.insert();
    }
}
```

DataSourceConfiguration.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="sbjdev" />
    <property name="password" value="sbjdev" />
</bean>
<bean id="UserDao" class="com.mPowerQuartz.common.Dao.UserDao.java">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace please?

Comment: can you add your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers they are..

**1)ApplicationContext and bean is not initialized, which will look like..**

ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("userconfig.xml");
    UserDao usr = (JobDetailsDao) ctx.getBean("UDao");

**2)In configuration xml, Dao and Dao implementation are not mapper. Which looks like.**

```
<bean id="UserDao" class="com.mPowerQuartz.common.DaoImpl.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate"> <ref bean = "jdbcTemplate" ></ref> 
        </property> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is most likely thrown by your own code.

And it's most likely thrown because the dataSource field of the UserDao is null.

The reason for that is that you're not using Spring correctly. Instead of asking Spring to create the UserDao and inject the DataSource in that Spring bean, you're creating the UserDao yourself, using `new`. So no Spring context is ever used, and Spring doesn't play any role in your code.

Read the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-basics) to understand how to create a Spring application context and get a bean from it.